# Difference between bounds inside a where clause and "inline" bounds

Tags: rust

Consider [the following example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcdbe807dbd8f801e89eddf4d8077a11):

```rust
fn where_clause<T, F>(mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T),
{
        
}

fn inline<T>(mut f: FnMut(&T)) {
        
}
```

`where_clause()` is compiled well, whereas `inline()` gives the problem:

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
```

Adding `dyn` leads to:

```
the size for values of type `(dyn for<'r> FnMut(&'r T) + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

Could you please explain why these bounds give different results?

Comment: I suggest reading the [chapter on trait objects in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Comment: The second one should probably be `mut f: impl FnMut(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please explain why these bounds give different results?

Well, because `inline<T>` *does not have* any bounds. If you want bounds with the inline syntax, you can do so as follows:

```rust
fn inline<T, F: FnMut(&T)>(mut f: F) {
        
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c7867fd1333bb894af35c3e0eacf7d2)

In your `inline<T>` function, the `f` parameter is *not* a generic type, but a trait object (that *contains* the generic type `T`).

Answer (score 0):

Stop thinking about polymorphism (and variance): A structure implementing a trait "is" not that trait.
In other words a concrete function is not FnMut(...).

If you now try to specify your parameter as `mut f: FnMut(&T)` you tell the compiler you explicitly want such an `FnMut(&T)` which is not possible. Sort of like in java you can not direktly instantiate an abstract class or an interface.

So instead you can tell the compiler with `dyn FnMut(&T)` i want *something* that implements this trait. Kind of runtime polymorphism. But since runtime values have no known size at compile time (which rust requires) you get the mentioned error. Solution might be a reference to such a thing `&dyn FnMut(&T)`.

Lastly the generic parameter. This is an other way of saying *something*. But static. So when you call the function you pass concrete arguments and as such concrete types and concrete sizes for the value. Everything rust does is ensuring, that whatever this *something* is, it will be in the specified bounds and then it creates a specific version of your function for those calls.

This answer might not be formally correct but should give some general intuition.